# How to map a function with boolean operators over an array?

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I am a beginner in Mathematica. I have this in Mathematica v12:

```
A = {1, 1, 1, 1}
B = {2, 2, 2, 2}
A+B
(* 3,3,3,3 *)
```

I'd like to experiment with evaluating arbitrary expressions on arrays, like this:

```
C = {4, 2, 4, 2}
(A+B)<C
(* I want this output: *)
(* True, False, True, False *)
```

In the example, above:

- `{1,1,1,1} + {2,2,2,2}` evaluates to `{3,3,3,3}` which is an element-wise operation.
- `{3,3,3,3} < {4,2,4,2}` should evaluate to `{ True, False, True, False }`, but it does not do an element-wise operation (which seems logically inconsistent!).

#### What I have tried

Tried about 30 combinations and permutations of existing functions, none of them appeared to work. Tried the top 6 answers that were vaguely relevant on SO. Browsed through Mathematica documentation to try and find anything relevant.

Comment: In haskell: zipWith (<) (zipWith (+) [1,1,1,1] [2,2,2,2]) [4,2,4,2]

Comment: In python: `[x+y<z for x,y,z in zip([1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[4,2,4,2])]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Can generalize this to account for scalars using `ReplaceRepeated` and some pattern matching.

```
bolVectorEval[exp_] := 
 exp //. h_[params : OrderlessPatternSequence[_List .., _?NumericQ ...]] :> 
   Thread[h[params]]
```

then

```
bolVectorEval[(a > c) || (4.3 < (b + c))]
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, False}
> ```

**OP**

You may use `Thread`.

```
Thread[(a + b) < c]
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, False}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! The first answer works perfectly to evaluate expressions with logical operators such as || or &&, e.g. `bolVectorEval[((a + b) > (c + a)) || (a > c)]`. @Henrik Schumacher also recommended BoolEval by Szabolcz, that works perfectly as well, and claims to be optimised for efficiency. Example: `BoolEval[((a + b) > (c + a)) || (a > c)]`.

Answer (score 6):

You may exploit that `UnitStep` step is vectorized like this:

```
a = {1, 1, 1, 1};
b = {2, 2, 2, 2};
c = {4, 2, 4, 2};
{False, True}[[2 - UnitStep[(a + b) - c]]]
```

> {True, False, True, False}

If you can life with `0` and `1` instead of `False` and `True`, the the following will serve your needs and is more efficient (for large lists):

```
Subtract[1, UnitStep[Subtract[(a + b), c]]]
```

In particular, it is two orders of magnitude faster than `Thread`:

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {n}];
b = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {n}];
c = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {n}];

r1 = Thread[(a + b) < c]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = Subtract[1, UnitStep[Subtract[(a + b), c]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
And @@ ({False, True}[[r2 + 1]] == r1)
```

> 0.34
>
> 0.0025
>
> True

But of course, `Thread` is more convenient and also more readible.

Szabolcs wrote a nice packaged that gives you the best of both worlds: It's called [BoolEval](https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm after a more general solver, i.e. I could plug in `(a+b)>c` or even `((a+b)>(c+d)) || (a>d)`, and it would do an element-wise apply of that function to get something like `{ True, False, True, False }`

Comment: `Unitize[UnitStep[(a + b) - (c + d)] + UnitStep[a - d]]` ;) But I see your point. Szabolcz wrote a nice packaged with the name [BoolEval](https://github.com/szhorvat/BoolEval). Have a look!

Comment: BoolEval works brilliantly, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've marked the answer by @Edmund as the one that worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: add example for BoolEval `ResourceFunction["BoolEval"][A + B < {4, 2, 4, 2}] /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}`

Answer (score 4):

```
vecLess = Negative @* Subtract;

vecLess[a + b, c]
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, False}
> ```

```
a + b < c /. Less -> vecLess
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, False}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very idiosyncratic way of handling the problem. This would be my goto method if I just needed to get things done and didn't care about performance. It's  not the easiest to read, but there's a lot going on that someone new to MMA can learn from:

```
a = {1, 1, 1, 1};
b = {2, 2, 2, 2};
c = {4, 2, 4, 2};
#1+#2<#3&@@@Transpose[{a,b,c}]
```

> {True, False, True, False}

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) post is a great place to start if you're just getting into Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you, and that post you referenced is amazing.